# read field values without loading the user objects in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

If I have a known set of users eg. by UID $users = {123, 435, 5463, 5678}.  And I want to read the value stored in one custom field e.g. field_current_status that has been added to their user object is there any way to read this 1 value for each of them without loading their user objects.

I don't want to load up a lot of data for a lot of users just to get 1 value from each user.

I have looked at many functions including these below;

- field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, $field_name, $langcode = NULL)
- field_view_field($entity_type, $entity, $field_name, $display = array(), $langcode = NULL)
- field_view_value($entity_type, $entity, $field_name, $item, $display = array(), $langcode = NULL)
- user_load_multiple($uids = array(), $conditions = array(), $reset = FALSE)

These all require the the user object to be loaded e.g. with user_load($uid) or in effect do the same.

Is there any Drupal way to do this or must I write a custom DB query?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this in Drupal would be to load the users with `user_load_multiple($user_uids)`, this saves overhead in database queries by loading all objects at the same time. You can then just loop over the users and extract the required field:

```
$users = user_load_multiple($user_uids);
if (!$users) {
  return FALSE;
}

foreach ($users as $user) {
  $field_current_status = field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_current_status');
  if (!$field_current_status) {
    continue;
  }

  // Handle $field_current_status.
}
```

In terms of memory unless you were loading a massive number of users, you shouldn't really have a problem - Drupal itself has a high demand for memory. If memory is still a concern for you then you can use `db_select()` or `db_query()` to contruct a query to join the field_current_status table with the users table.

If this is a process that need to happen often then it may be worth looking into scheduling the cron to do it chunk by chunk.

Comment: thanks and I appreciate the effort but as I mentioned I have already considered user_load_multiple, this is a frequent process that could require looking at hundreds of users.  It cannot be scheduled because it is event driven.  I will look at db_select() and db_query().